# Regex Transform or Text Replace in Text Editor

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do an advanced text search and replace in a text editor (I can use SublimeText or VSCode)

**Input:**

```
parameters['myParameter1']
parameters['myParameter2']
```

**Expected output:**

```
myParameter1
myParameter2
```

And I have hundreds of similar scenario in the file. So that's why I'm thinking of using regex to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fcWdSi/1)

**Regex search:** `parameters\['([^']+)'\]`

> **1.** `parameters\['` this will match `parameters['` Optinally if you have other keywords then `parameters` and which can be dynamic for that you can use `[a-zA-Z]+` this will include all lower case and upper case.
>
> **2.** `([^']+)` this will match all except `'`, `()` will capture first match in `$1`.
>
> **3.** `'\]` this will match ending `']`

**Replacement:** `$1`

> **Note:** If you are using `gedit` `ubuntu` you have to replace it with `\1`

Comment: Nice this is what I needed! :D

Answer (score 0):

VSCode can search all files in a directory, and it supports RegExp too!

Use `ctrl+shift+f` to search all files, hit the `.*` icon for RegExp.
A search expression such as `parameters['(.*)']` replaced with `$1` should work!

Check out the official guide for more info: [VSCode Basic Editing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files)